# FireStore Rules : Read/Write user own document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore I have 2 collections

A users collection and a periods collection. I need a rule for my period collection : Read and write only by the user who create the period.

users collection look like
[image]

periods collection look like
[image]

This is what I try with no success

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function userDoc() {
      return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /periods/{id} {
        allow read : if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user;
        allow write : if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just store the user UID only in the period doc and use `request.resource.data.user === request.auth.uid`, or am I missing anything ?

Comment: I try this. it doesn't work. in periods user_id is equal to users/PdqJAiVsUDOQfCT5GA3jgOvQZQT2. See my sample data

Comment: That's because `request.auth.uid` is only `PdqJAiVsUDOQfCT5GA3jgOvQZQT2` and not prefixed with `/users`. Can you add another field `user_uid` maybe and try with that?

Comment: I'm trying to get a prefixed users/ with userDoc() function but it's not working ;-(

Comment: I just try this : "users/${request.auth.uid}" == request.resource.data.user_id;
But it did not work....

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user`

with

`if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user_id`

Other than that your security rule looks correct to me.

Comment: It's works for create, update but something wrong with read/delete :     match /periods/{id} {
      allow read, delete : if  userDoc() == request.resource.data.user_id; 
      allow create, update : if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user_id;
    }

Answer (score 1):

- The object ‘request.resource.data.user’ doesn’t exist in your periods collection so it should be changed to ‘request.resource.data.user_id’.
- Also the read and delete request doesn’t have a ‘request.resource’ object. So for the read and delete request, ‘request.resource.data.user_id’ should be replaced with ‘resource.data.user_id’.
- I would suggest you to use more granular rules for write requests i.e. create, update, delete. For more details on firestore rules you can refer to [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language).

For your use case please see the below firestore rule sample.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function userDoc() {
      return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /periods/{id} {
        allow read, delete : if userDoc() == resource.data.user_id;
        allow update : if userDoc() == request.resource.data.user_id;
        allow create : if userDoc() == /databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.user_id.path);
    }
  }
}
```